# View with multiple blocks, how to specify which is shown?

Tags: 8, views, blocks

I have a view that is placed as a block below my main content. Within that view I have block "displays". each having a different contextual filter for their id from url.

The problem is when the view is displayed, it only shows one of the Displays, how do i specify which is shown ?

[image]

Comment: Any particular Block is showing only one Display from Views, not all of them. If you have 2 Block Displays you need to add the 2 related Blocks to the theme region to show both of them.

Comment: But how do you specify which display is chosen ?

Comment: You can name them differently in each Display, so when you go to place a Block in a region you will recognize which one is which by their names. You will see both listed.

Comment: Yes I see now, there is two block variants in the place block dialog for each display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place a block, it give you option to select between the different named variants (displays) within the view.